# How to loop an array from lower values to upper values in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular js,i want loop an array from lower value to upper values in li tag.I am declaring an array with values in ng-init directive.I tried to use orderBy ,but it is not working.How to get it done ?

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>My Page</title>
  </head>

 <body ng-app="">
   <div ng-init="marks=[20,10,15,30,18,21,35]">
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="m in marks | orderBy:'marks'">{{m}}</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort by the array elements themselves and not by their properties, you can use `toString()` to sort by their string values, or `valueOf()` if they are numeric values:

```
<li ng-repeat="m in marks | orderBy:'valueOf()'">{{m}}</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yynLkyh/3/

To sort in descending order, you can append a `-` before the function call:

```
<li ng-repeat="m in marks | orderBy:'-valueOf()'">{{m}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>My Page</title>
  </head>

 <body ng-app="">
   <div ng-init="marks=[20,10,15,30,18,21,35]">
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="m in marks | orderBy:'+'">{{m}}</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Changes

> ng-repeat="m in marks | orderBy:'+'"  **FOR ACCESSING**
>
> ng-repeat="m in marks | orderBy:'-'"  **FOR DECESSDING**